# Javascript Queue commands

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

I have a Tab widget set up on my website using JQuery 1.7.2 and JQuery UI 1.10.3.

I have written a JavaScript that parses the hash part of a URL in order that I can open a tab, load content into a div and scroll to a named anchor.

I can get the tab to open and content to load fine, however, scrolling to the anchor is proving to be a real pain.

I can get it to work if I trigger an alert before the scroll to the anchor (forcing you to click 'OK', but if I disable the alert (which I want to), it doesn't work.

I am guessing that it has something to do with waiting for the functions to finish processing first? But I'm quite inexperienced with JavaScript so would appreciate any help anyone could could give.

```
URL example: http://www.mysite.com/abc.html#tab=tab-3&#srv=includes/xyz&#anc=myanchor
```

My JavaScript is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var parts = location.hash;
    parts = parts.split('&'); // Hash parts of URL. 

    for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) // Loop to separate variables. 
    {
        if (parts[i].substr(1, 4).toUpperCase() == "TAB=") {
            var tab = parts[i].substr(5).split("-").pop() - 1
        } // Tab no. part from tab name.
        if (parts[i].substr(1, 4).toUpperCase() == "SRV=") {
            var srv = parts[i].substr(5)
        } // Path to content to load.
        if (parts[i].substr(1, 4).toUpperCase() == "ANC=") {
            var anc = parts[i].substr(5)
        } // Named anchor to locate.
    };

    // Tab found in URL so we'll check it exists and open it. 
    if (tab == -1) // Tab not found?
    {
        tab = 0 // Default to 1st tab if not.
    };

    $("#tabs").tabs("option", "active", tab); // Select the tab.

    // Load content if provided in URL.
    var href = $('.list li a').each(function () {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        if (srv == href.substr(0, href.length - 5)) {
            var toLoad = srv + '.html .maint_content';
            $('.maint_content').load(toLoad)
        }
    });

    // Load content when selected from list.
    $('.list li a').click(function () {
        var toLoad = $(this).attr('href') + ' .maint_content';
        $('.maint_content').fadeOut('normal', loadContent);
        $('#load').remove();
        $('.maint_content').fadeIn('normal', loadContent);
        $('#load').fadeIn('normal');
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0, $(this).attr('href').length - 5);

        function loadContent() {
            $('.maint_content').load(toLoad, '', showNewContent());
        }

        function showNewContent() {
            $('.maint_content').show('normal', hideLoader());
        }

        function hideLoader() {
            $('#load').fadeOut('normal');
        }
        return false;
    });

    // Scroll to locate anchor.
    //alert(anc);
    $('html, body').animate({
        'scrollTop': $('#' + anc).offset().top
    }, 1000);

});
```

Thanks

Comment: Please format your code. It is very hard to read.

Comment: instead of doing a possibly infinite number of http requests by using a load in a loop, a better practice would be too consolidate all the info you're passing into one request, and then use a loop to parse the results instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the anchor you want to jump to is in the loaded content?

If so, just add a callback to the ajax call and do the jump there:

```
$('.maint_content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent()).done(function () {
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-5);
});
```

Comment: HI Frits, could you show where exactly to implement that code?

Answer (score 0):

You are ajaxing the content of the div. This means it is loading asynchronously. The animate function is thus called before the loading of the content has finished, and the anchor you are looking for is not yet there.

In order to fire the animation when the loading is complete, you can pass a function to `.load()`

```
$('.maint_content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent());
```

so you allready got that: `showNewContent` is fired when the loading finishes.
So all you have to do is move your animation line to the end of that function.

```
function showNewContent() 
{ 
    $('.maint_content').show('normal',hideLoader());
    $('html, body').animate({'scrollTop': $('#'+anc).offset().top}, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nicky, your suggestion makes a lot of sense.  I tried it but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: maybe try and make a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to demonstrate your problem, so it's easier to see and fix the problem.